# UML: Same component in two different places

Tags: uml

How to draw a component diagram where the same component is used in multiple places?

Do I simply draw the same component twice?

Comment: reusing components is good.

Comment: You are mixing with instances here. Be precise, please.

Comment: hmm. Is a component diagram same as the circuit diagram in electronics? Just like it is a connection between components. It is possible that the circuit has two capacitors. I get that idea from this image: https://www.visual-paradigm.com/VPGallery/diagrams/Component.html

Comment: For example, I have a component that reads a file. I have two different files to read, so I use that reader twice for reading in different data. Do I need to draw two readers or just one reader? The reader only take one input, the file name. Drawing just one reader that takes in two input filenames is not right.

Comment: A component is something abstract (a transistor type for ex.). You are probably talking about instances (the two transistors on your board).

Comment: I get the idea now: http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/componentDiagram.htm So components are more like modules or a circuit board in a system with multiple circuit boards.

Comment: Yes and no. They are anonymous. The picture in a catalog. When you buy 2 you get two instances. I'll try to explain it in an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not clear about the use of instances. Components are just blueprints you can use and re-use.

In this example we use a `Motor` which is associated with either a `Boat` or a `Car`. It's an (abstract) component which means that the imagination cloud will include gas, diesel, steam, rubber band, electrical or any other kind of motor. The context where this is used might fence this a bit more. But it's definitely not meaning the motor in your personal car.

[image]

As you see this `Motor` can be re-used in the model to be associated with a `Boat` or `Car`. Also note that it's not clear here whether it's used for driving or to remote control the back mirror.

Now for something more concrete.

[image]

The `Motor` and `Car` are now two distinct physical things. Re-using the `Motor` with this serial number somewhere else would mean you could no longer use it in this Volkswagen.

If you have an interface between things you can re-use the same instance (though not at the same time)

[image]

like the above wheel could be easily re-mounted on different cars with the same mounting holes. (Don't bother that there's only one wheel for the car.)

Just as thought food: you can also use Generalization with components. E.g. you can classify different motor types. Components are not so much different from classes. It's more or less just that components are a cluster of different classes working together.

Comment: Hi, a question, if vW Beetle:car is an instance, normally it should be underline no ? Like classes ?

Comment: @granier Hmm. Good question. I just sketched it with EA and did not spot that.  Will consult the specs.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, in fact I read the spec to understand the assembly link, and after reading the spec I was confused about component, component instances, interface provided-required and so on. So your answer will be welcome.

Comment: @granier You are right. 9.8.4 Notation on p. 126 tells so. Time for another bug report...

Comment: @kilian but if you look to figure 11.4 it use w : Wheel, for me (but maybe I am wrong) this is the instance named w of component Wheel and the full name is not underline. And I understood that assembly link may be used on instance only (again maybe I am wrong) and on figure 11.8 the names are not underlined

Comment: @granier Strange. Seems to contradict. I sent a bug report to Sparx. Will see what they say. I also sent 2 bug reports to OMG in the latest time. Probably they created this with EA xD

Comment: @kilian, fun :) a more general question, it is possible to create bug on the OMG document ? Everyone can do that ?

Comment: @granier Yes, everyone can do that: http://issues.omg.org/issues/lists/unclassified

Comment: Sparx has confirmed this to be a bug fixed in a later EA version.

Comment: great, in our company, we use ea also, so this is interesting ;)